# How to avoid unnecessary if statements every update based on boolean value that does not change after being set

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization

If I have the following:

```
bool type;

int main();
{
        type = false;
}


void update()
{
        if( type == false )
        {
                //do something
        }
        else
        {
                //do something else
        }

}
```

The code will set the value of type to either true or false, using an if statement will cause the compiler to check what the value is every update, I want to avoid this and only do one check since the type will be set and then not changed. Is there some way to make it only check once?

Comment: make the bool `constexpr` and use `if constexpr`

Comment: IMHO this is a great example for turning conditionals into polymorphism; you construct an appropriate object based on the condition, and then use that object afterwards. Kind of like the strategy pattern.

Comment: Consider providing two `update` functions and using a function pointer instead. One version would assume `type` is `false` and the other would assume `type` is `true`. A `bool` template argument may be useful for this. Then you only need to set the pointer to the right function when your `type` is set.

Comment: I would like to believe the branch prediction in your CPU will do a great job.

Comment: @dave: Certainly a possibility, but we should also mention that this approach only works if you know the condition at compile time.

Comment: where do you modify `type` ? It is difficult to give concrete advice, because if you set it at runtime, you need that condition in one way or the other. Please try to make your example more complete ([mcve])

Comment: I agree with @MikeCAT . I don't quite agree with @ FrançoisAndrieux or @ AndyG 's method (on speed concern at least) (as branch vs virtual call.)

Comment: @appleapple: a virtual method call is going to be roughly the same overhead as indirection through a function pointer. Sometimes one will be faster and sometimes the other will be. And sometimes they will be faster than branch prediction and sometimes they won't be.

Comment: @AndyG yes, I mean it would probably not solve what OP want (speed, afaict), sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @appleapple: The main issue with such a boolean is that it often violates SRP. Refactoring to make it checked only once is necessary for clean code. On top of that, sure, branch prediction might be fast enough, but depending on how many other branches are in the code it may not be great.

Comment: @AndyG Refactoring a free function with a branch to polymorphism is kinda extreme. Particularly so if the (perhaps unwise) concern is performance.

Comment: @PasserBy: The user needs indirection either way to solve their issue (avoiding the check of a boolean every time they want to update). In OPs case the boolean is a global variable, but that is isomorphic to it being an implicit parameter of all functions. And boolean parameters are generally frowned upon, esp. if the intention is for the boolean to be unchanging. All proposals outside of "let branch prediction do it" boil down to creating two "callable" things just once before any call to "update". type erasure through a function pointer, a `std::function` or polymorphism are all valid to me.

Comment: @AndyG Polymorphism introduces a new *set* of types *and* a hierachy when there was none. The global is horrendous, sure. `std::function` might be better.

Comment: @PasserBy: `std::function` uses polymorphism internally :-) The overhead for it is much more than you might think.

Comment: @AndyG I know pretty well what they cost, but that wasn't the point. You are generating artificial complexity to a simple problem. You don't use the thickest layer of abstraction everywhere you go just because you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223777/discussion-between-andyg-and-passer-by).